# Como validar preexistencia de identifacion con archivos en C?

Tags: c, archivo

Buenas estoy teniendo problemas para validar un ID de un archivo en C. Resulta que mi programa es un sistema, te registras con ID y nombre y todo esto lo guardo en un struct con archivos. El problema es que se me pide que no se puede repetir el ID de la persona y se tiene que validar. Yo habia pensado en esta funcion pero no me valida el dato. Alguna sugerencia de que puedo hacer?

```
    int checkDato(char *nombrearchivo, int dato){
        int band=0;

while (!feof(f)){
    fscanf(f,"%s\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d",personas.nombre,&personas.cedula,&personas.diab,&personas.mesb,&personas.anob);
    if( (dato == personas.cedula) ){
        band = 1;
        printf("hola entre, son iguales");
        break;
    }
}

if (band == 1){
    printf("Son iguales");
}else if (band == 0){
    printf("Son distintos");
}


return band;
```

Como aclaratoria, yo tengo mi struct declarada previamente de esta forma

```
typedef struct {
    int cedula;
    char nombre[15];
    int  diab;
    int  mesb;
    int  anob;
}personas;
```

Y la llamada de verificacion la pense asi:

```
if ( checkDato("PersonasInfo.txt",atoi(cedu))==1){
    printf("Cedula repetida");
}
```

Y mi ingreso de datos seria asi..

```
char cedu[10];
printf("\t\tIntroduzca la cedula de la persona\n");
printf (" ->"); fgets(cedu,10,stdin);
verif(cedu);

if ( checkDato("PersonasInfo.txt",atoi(cedu))){
    printf("Cedula repetida");
}

if (let(cedu)){
    printf("\nLa cedula digitada contiene caracteres\n");
    contC++;
    printf("Tiene %d intento de 3 para digitar el dia correcto\n",contC);
}


if (contC==3){
    personasS();
}


personas.cedula = atoi(cedu);
```

Aclaro que LET es simplemente una funcion para verificar si el numero tiene caracteres o no, no es nada relevante en lo que estoy preguntando. Simplemente pongo el ingreso de datos de la persona por su cedula o ID como le quieran llamar.

Comment: Eso.. esta casi perfecto.. le sobra un break;, que no se porque le pusiste a las dos partes del if.. vos queres cortar solamente cuando lo encontraste. no cuando no lo encontraste... saca el break que sobra, y va a funcionar todo de maravilla....

Comment: PAra que te sea mas simple.. te sobra todo el else que esta dentro del while.. si sacas eso.. anda todo perfecto...

Comment: Intente sacarle como me dijiste el else en el ciclo o quitarle ese break que era innecesario , y ahora cuando estoy digitando la cedula, despues de hacerlo el programa se cuelga... :( . Probe poniendo un mensaje ahi en el else para ver si entra, y claro que entra pero el programa imprime lo mismo muchas veces. Se queda colgado.

Comment: Y otra vez estas leyendo desordenado?

Comment: No, estoy leyendo como esta en el fscanf no he modificado nada de ahi.

Answer (score 0):

Para el que tenga este problema, la solución radica en  abrir el archivo antes de meter los datos con el fopen() para asi no entrar en bucle.